# Is there a way to "unmark" a file?

Tags: mercurial

If I mark a "missing" file (indicated by a `!`) for remove, (for example this can be done by accidentally finding the wrong rename), how do I unmark it, and get it to be "missing" again? I find that the file becomes stuck at `R` state, and then `hg rename` will give a message like `not copying - file has been marked for remove`. There are various commands like `remove` which will `mark` a file to take some action on the next commit, but is there a way to clear this flag and return the file back to the unmarked state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually if you have sth. like this

```
! foo.txt
```

One possible solution:

```
hg revert foo.txt
```

Or you can update only the file to latest revision without a conflict like

```
hg update -r <rev-id> foo.txt
```

Usually

```
hg log
```

should give enough information to perform this step

If you want any further help, please post output of

```
hg status && hg log
```

Comment: ok, `hg revert foo.txt` works for a missing file that was marked to remove, if I then also delete the file that it restored. I was hoping for a command like `hg unmark` that would just remove whatever mark a file might have gotten and return it to the unmarked state.